# How to extract a part of xml code from an xml file using c# code

Tags: c#, xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
 <eRecon xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="eRecon.xsd">
 <Header>
  <Company Code="" /> 
  <CommonCarrierCode /> 
  <InputFileName InputIDPk="">F:\ReconNew\TmesysRec20100111.rec</InputFileName> 
  <BatchNumber>000152</BatchNumber> 
  <InputStartDateTime>2010-02-26 11:47:00</InputStartDateTime> 
  <InputFinishDateTime>2010-02-26 11:47:05</InputFinishDateTime> 
  <RecordCount>8</RecordCount> 
  </Header>
 <Detail>
  <CarrierStatusDate>2010-01-11</CarrierStatusDate> 
  <ClaimNum>YDF02892 C</ClaimNum> 
  <InvoiceNum>0108013775</InvoiceNum> 
  <LineItemNum>001</LineItemNum> 
  <NABP>10600211</NABP> 
  <RxNumber>4695045</RxNumber> 
  <RxDate>2008-07-21</RxDate> 
  <CheckNum /> 
  <PaymentStatus>PENDING</PaymentStatus> 
  <RejectDescription /> 
  <InvoiceChargeAmount>152.15</InvoiceChargeAmount> 
  <InvoicePaidAmount>131.00</InvoicePaidAmount> 
 </Detail>
 </eRecon>
```

How can I  extract the portion

```
 <Header>
  <Company Code="" /> 
  <CommonCarrierCode /> 
  <InputFileName InputIDPk="">F:\ReconNew\TmesysRec20100111.rec</InputFileName> 
  <BatchNumber>000152</BatchNumber> 
  <InputStartDateTime>2010-02-26 11:47:00</InputStartDateTime> 
  <InputFinishDateTime>2010-02-26 11:47:05</InputFinishDateTime> 
  <RecordCount>8</RecordCount> 
 </Header>
```

from the above xml file.

I need the c# code to extract a part of xml tag from an xml file.

Comment: I need the code to extract any part of the xml tag from the given xml file, not only header part.Any xml part have to be extracted.

Answer (score 4):

If the file isn't too big (smaller than a few MB), you can load it into an `XmlDocument`:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\yourfile.xml");
```

and then you can parse for the `<Header>` element using an XPath expression:

```
XmlNode headerNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/eRecon/Header");
if(headerNode != null)
{
    string headerNodeXml = headerNode.OuterXml;
}
```

Comment: I need the code to extract any part of the xml tag from the given xml file, not only header part.Any xml part have to be extracted.I just showed to extract header part as an example.Please help me.

Comment: @user578104: if you need to extract another section, just adapt the XPath expression! The `/eRecon/Header` string defines what to extract - if you need something else, just adapt this. Learn XPath!

Comment: @user578104: See [W3Schools XPath Introduction](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_intro.asp) for learning how to express what you need in XPath

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath like in this tutorial:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/myXPath.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq-to-xml:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\sample.xml");
var header = xmlDoc.Descendants("Header").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I need the code to extract any part of the xml tag from the given xml file, not only header part.Any xml part have to be extracted.I just showed to extract header part as an example.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Linq version

```
string fileName=@"d:\xml.xml";
var descendants = from i in XDocument.Load(fileName).Descendants("Header")
select i;
```

Comment: I need the code to extract any part of the xml tag from the given xml file, not only header part.Any xml part have to be extracted.I just showed to extract header part as an example.Please help me.